# What to do with tag "qt-layout"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just noticed that there is a [qt-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-layout) tag, but since there is also a [qlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlayout) tag, I am kinda lost whether it is useful. They seem to be used for the same purpose as of now. Neither has really that many questions.

Since the official Qt class is called `QLayout` and then that tag has slightly more entries, I would propose to either make a [qlayout synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qlayout/synonyms) to [qt-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-layout) or just retag the questions in [qt-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-layout) to [qlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qlayout).

Perhaps, there is even a reason to keep it. One could argue that it could be used for both C++ and QML technology. At this point, it just feels a bit out of place with my Qt hat on as there are no QML layout questions, only C++. I do not expect them coming soon, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep them both.

qt-layout refers to Qt layout management. Qt has a set of layout classes. QLayout is the base class of geometry managers.

qt-layout should be used for Qt layout management specific questions, not for QLayout or QLayoutItem specific questions.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Comment: That is Qt 4, which is old, but I think I get your point. You see the point for each very small tag on the site, right? If others think it is useful, we can keep it, but at the very least, the tag wikis should be added.

Comment: layout management is more the "layout" specific stuff. (less the "technical" programming specific). << I don't know how to clarify my point.

Comment: We have a layout tag (without the qt- prefix) for that. Stack Overflow is a bit of tag zoo at times. :-)

Comment: Would it be possible that you document the tag wiki for what you would like to use it? I am flexible as long as it is documented, even if it is only needed by a few questions over the course of a year.

Comment: yes i can do this

Comment: Cool, I will accept your answer when you are ready with that.

Comment: I edited the tag wiki. (my entry needs reviewing)

Comment: Thanks, I approved it myself, but can you please also add some notes about QML or it would be explicitly about C++ Layouts in the widgets world?

Comment: Thanks, almost forgot about QMLs anchor based layout. I added QML and posted the final version of the tag documentation.